# javabuilders maven dependencies are not found in jcenter repository

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, jcenter

I'm currently working on a java project that uses maven to manage dependencies.

In this project, I would like to use the javabuilders library. According to the [documentation](https://github.com/jacek99/javabuilders), my `pom.xml` file should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project
  xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>fr.my.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <url>http://jcenter.bintray.com/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javabuilders</groupId>
      <artifactId>core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javabuilders</groupId>
      <artifactId>swing-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javabuilders</groupId>
      <artifactId>swing-glazedlists</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
      <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  <testResources>
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/java</directory>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*</include>
      </includes>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
      </excludes>
    </testResource>
  </testResources>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
      <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <includes>
        <include>**/*.yml</include>
        <include>**/*.java</include>
      </includes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

The issue is that the dependencies are not found :

> javabuilders:swing-core:1.3.0 not found.

It seems that the dependencies are not searched into jcenter. Should I add something more in my `pom.xml` file or maybe into my `settings.xml` file ?

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: The groupId `javabuilders` is not a groupId that is used on [Maven central](http://mvnrepository.com), so you probably have to add it as dependency with scope `system` or install it manually in your local maven repository.

Comment: I know, it is why I added the repositories tag into my pom.XML file. But it seems that the repo is not targeted...

Comment: it's definitely [in jcenter](https://bintray.com/bintray/jcenter?filterByPkgName=swing-glazedlists).

Comment: @JBaruch : yes, I know ;) But why my pom.XML file does not work ? :(

Comment: We'll investigate, but let's start with changing the title of the question to be true. Is this the only dependency that you use?

Comment: @JBaruch : I have edited my message with the full `pom.xml` file. The only other dependency I use is joda-time that is found correctly.

Comment: Since you add repositories to the pom file (instead of replacing the default repositories in the `settings.xml` as instructed on Set Me Up screen of Bintray) we actually don't know where joda time comes from. It might very well be, for example, that your org blocks access to Bintray and joda time comes from Maven Central.